# save the result of lookup_users method in json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to fetch user metadata using tweepy by user screen name and save the result as JSON file. Here is my code

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxx'
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    # A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to standard output

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)
#search
api = tweepy.API(auth)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,TweetListener())

#name is list contains user screen names
test = api.lookup_users(screen_names= name)
for user in test:
    print (user.screen_name)
    print (user.name)
    print (user.description)
    print (user.followers_count)
    print (user.statuses_count)
```

my code runs without any error and as you can see, I am printing the data but my intend is to save them in JSON file 
I tried different cods but nothing works for me. So please any help?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a way to save data in specific format.
In order to save your data, you first need to store it properly, and then just dump it.
the format is dict, that holds data separated by keys, and each key is a map.
in your case, I chose 'users' as a key.
each user in 'users' have keys (name, descripition, etc) and values from your list.

you need to do something like that:

```
import json

data = {'users': []}
for user in test:
    data['users'].append({
        'screen_name': user.screen_name,
        'name': user.name,
        'description': user.description,
        'followers_count': user.followers_count,
        'statuses_count': user.statuses_count
    })

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: thank you.  It worked but because most of descriptions and other fields are in arabic language this is how appear in the file 
{"screen_name": "AliAbd87895756", "name": "\u0639\u0644\u064a \u0646\u0635\u0627\u0631", "description": "\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0633 \644\u0643 \ud83d\udc4d\ud83e\udd1a", "followers_count": 89, "statuses_count": 1038}

is there any way to save them as arabic language

Comment: try to add this in the beggining of the file:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

also, change the dump to be like this:
with open('data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:

Comment: thanks for your reply but I still get the same output and the problem not solved